# Incorporating jsPDF to your already existing Vuetify project

Tags: pdf, vue.js, npm, jspdf, vuetify.js

I am trying to incorporate **jsPDF** to my already existing **Vuejs** project to generate PDF outputs. However when I run `npm i jsPDF --save` in the terminal it gives me an error saying:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: jsPDF@latest
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: try with `npm install jspdf --save` instead of `jsPDF`

Comment: worked, thank you so much :)

Comment: may you select my answer as the correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `npm install jspdf --save` instead of `jsPDF` since the name of a package is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

The package on npm is under "jspdf" not "jsPDF" so:

```
npm install jspdf --save
```